# Replace .env parameter with content of a file

Tags: php, symfony, environment-variables

I want to replace a parameter in my .env with content of a file when installing dependencies.

I've this in my docker-compose.yml under the specific php-container:

```
command:
    - /bin/sh
    - -c
    - |
        date +%s | sha256sum | base64 | head -c 32 > passphrase.txt
        openssl genrsa -out config/jwt/private.pem -aes256 -passout file:passphrase.txt 4096
        openssl rsa -passin file:passphrase.txt -pubout -in config/jwt/private.pem -out config/jwt/public.pem
        composer install
        php bin/console --no-interaction doctrine:migrations:migrate
```

Now when composer runs, the parameter of JWT_PASSPHRASE should be replaced with the content of passphrase.txt:

```
###> lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle ###
# Key paths should be relative to the project directory
JWT_PRIVATE_KEY_PATH=config/jwt/private.pem
JWT_PUBLIC_KEY_PATH=config/jwt/public.pem
JWT_PASSPHRASE=???
JWT_TOKEN_TTL=3600
###< lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle ###
```

Is that possible?

Best,
Christian

Comment: Yes, drop the command and use custom entrypoint script.

Comment: Yeah, would be a solution. And how do you replace that?

Comment: Remove `command`, add `entrypoint`. Quite simple.

Comment: Guy, you have no idea what my environment looks like or how my containers are configured, so stop talking nonsense. Using an entrypoint overrides the default entrypoint of the image I am using, which is a thing, i can't do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this just by exporting the JWT_PASSPHRASE. I do not need to write the passphrase into a file.

```
export JWT_PASSPHRASE=$(date +%s | sha256sum | base64 | head -c 32)
openssl genrsa -out config/jwt/private.pem -aes256 -passout pass:${JWT_PASSPHRASE}
openssl rsa -passin pass:${JWT_PASSPHRASE} -pubout -in ./config/jwt/private.pem -out ./config/jwt/public.pem
```